# export module state data via output

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My terraform state file has a following entry

```
tf state list
...
module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["core"].aws_iam_role.this[0]
...
```

What I need to export as an output is the name of this role

```
tf state show "module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group[\"core\"].aws_iam_role.this[0]"
# module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["core"].aws_iam_role.this[0]:
...
resource "aws_iam_role" "this" {
    arn                   = "arn:aws:iam::744734775600:role/core-eks-node-group-20220720190912617300000001"
...
    name                  = "core-eks-node-group-20220720190912617300000001"
```

I tried something like this

```
output "core_iam_role_name" {
  value = module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["core"].aws_iam_role.this[0]
}
```

but im getting the error

```
Terraform has been successfully initialized!
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on outputs.tf line 22, in output "core_iam_role_name":
│   22:   value = module.eks.module.eks_managed_node_group["core"].aws_iam_role.this[0]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.eks is a object, known only after apply
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "module".
```

I have other output values like

```
output "eks_managed_node_groups_autoscaling_group_names" {
  description = "List of the autoscaling group names created by EKS managed node groups"
  value       = flatten([for group in module.eks.eks_managed_node_groups : group.node_group_autoscaling_group_names])
}

output "eks_cluster_endpoint" {
  description = "value"
  value = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
}

output "eks_cluster_certificate_authority_data" {
  description = "value"
  value = module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data
}

output "eks_cluster_id" {
  description = "value"
  value = module.eks.cluster_id
}
```

but they work perfectly fine.

**EDIT**

The way the eks module is called is

```
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "18.26.4"
...
```

and then the eks module calls

```
module "eks_managed_node_group" {
  source = "./modules/eks-managed-node-group"
```

but thats all upstream.

Comment: Do you have access to the parent module, i.e., can you edit that? This seems kind of like an anti-pattern, because if you can change the module code there is no reason to query the state like this.

Comment: I have made an edit to my original question. the eks module is being pulled from the internet and is not on my local repo

Comment: You probably have to progressively output up the module declaration stack instead of all at once. You also may want to consider not doing nested module declarations.

Comment: What I need is the IAM role name associated with a node group. Alternatively is there a way to get a list of all IAM roles in an account ? I know that the role I want starts with `core-eks` so i can use regex to get the one I want

Comment: There is a set of output variables defined for some of the IAM roles, not sure if those roles are what you need: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/outputs.tf#L115-L128.

Comment: unfortunately thats only for the cluster. Im looking for the iam roles of the nodegroups.

Answer (score 1):

So turns out the standard output from the module is all I needed.

Specifying the following

```
output "core_iam_role_arn" {
  value = module.eks.eks_managed_node_groups
}
```

gives

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + name = {
      + core = {
          + iam_role_arn                       = "arn:aws:iam::744734775600:role/core-eks-node-group-20220720190912617300000001"
          + iam_role_name                      = "core-eks-node-group-20220720190912617300000001"
          + iam_role_unique_id                 = "AROA22ZNG3EYEBWHX7CGN"
          + launch_template_arn                = "arn:aws:ec2:ca-central-1:744734775600:launch-template/lt-08b223160310865a6"
          + launch_template_id                 = "lt-08b223160310865a6"
          + launch_template_latest_version     = 1
          + node_group_arn                     = "arn:aws:eks:ca-central-1:744734775600:nodegroup/dev-build/core-20220720192953013500000008/5cc10e8b-45d2-37d0-e884-c30e9302df91"
          + node_group_autoscaling_group_names = [
```

So all I needed to do was

```
output "core_iam_role_arn" {
  value = module.eks.eks_managed_node_groups["core"].iam_role_arn
}
```

which led to

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + core_iam_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::744734775600:role/core-eks-node-group-20220720190912617300000001"
```